# Как записать этот код без стрелочной фунции?

Tags: javascript

```
const girls = ['Alena', 'Malena', 'Milena', 'Asya', 'Kasya'];
const filterValues = (name) => {
    return girls.filter(data => {
        return data.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
}
console.log(filterValues('en'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто заменить стрелочные функции на обычные:

```
const filterValues = function(name) {
    return girls.filter(function(data) {
        return data.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
}
```